# Recursivly merge txt files in a batch

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, batch-file

I have one folder that contains several subfolders and each of those contains 10k+ small txt files. Now I need to merge all files from each subfolder into one big txt file for further processing.

If I call a batch manually in each folder which only contains `copy *.txt merge.txt /B` everything works fine.

But it would be better and easier if I could just call one batch file from the main which would perform the same task for each subfolder. I tried `for /r %%d in (.) do (copy *.txt merge.txt /B)` but without success. The error message is that *.txt can't be found which leads me to believe I can't just use the wildcard but rather would need to specify the files. But those are randomly generated.

Can you maybe help me out here on how I can merge those files. Thanks

Comment: `FOR /R` do not change current folder, you must specify it in the command. `for /r %%d in (.) do (copy "%%d\*.txt" "%%d\merge.txt" /B)`

Answer (score 0):

So let's say you have the following txt files in: %userprofile%\desktop\Mytext

[image]

You could use something like this:

```
@echo off
Rem put the root path to the txt files here:
set TxtPath=%userprofile%\desktop\MyText

if exist %userprofile%\desktop\merge.txt del %userprofile%\desktop\merge.txt

for /r %TxtPath% %%a in (*.txt) do more "%%a">> %userprofile%\desktop\merge.txt 
notepad.exe %userprofile%\desktop\merge.txt
```

And you would get a file called merge.txt on your desktop with the following content:

[image]

As an alternative, this code:

```
@echo off
Rem put the root path to the txt files here:
set TxtPath=%userprofile%\desktop\MyText

if exist %userprofile%\desktop\merge.txt del %userprofile%\desktop\merge.txt

for /r %TxtPath% %%a in (*.txt) do (
echo %%~nxa: >> %userprofile%\desktop\merge.txt
more "%%a">> %userprofile%\desktop\merge.txt 
echo. >> %userprofile%\desktop\merge.txt
)
notepad.exe %userprofile%\desktop\merge.txt
```

Would result in the following merge.txt file:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use **`where`** command to do this in **`for`** loop to copy your file/merge txt using **`cmd/bat`** or command line:

---

```bat
:: for command line ::
cd.>.\merge.txt & for /f tokens^=* %i in ('where /r "." "*.txt"')do copy /b /y .\merge.txt + "%~i" .\merge.txt

:: for cmd/bat file ::
@echo off 
cd.>.\merge.txt & for /f tokens^=* %%i in ('%__APPDIR__%where.exe /r "." "*.txt"')do copy /b /y .\merge.txt + "%%~i" .\merge.txt
```

Or without using `copy`....

```bat
@(for /r %i in (*.txt)do type "%~i")>merge.txt
```

---

> - But, you also can try do this by **`PowerShell`**:

```bat
Get-ChildItem -recurse -file *.txt | Get-Content | Set-Content merge.txt

:: or, using alias ::
gci -re -file *.txt | gc | sc merge.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I would let the [`for /R` loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html) resolve the file pattern rather than the `copy` command:

```cmd
rem // Prepare an empty result file to merge into:
> "merge.txt" rem/
rem // Merge one matching file after another, excluding the merge target file itself:
for /R %%I in ("*.txt") do if /I not "%%~nxI"=="merge.txt" copy "merge.txt" + "%%~I" "merge.txt" /B
```

The `for /R` command roots to the current working directory when no explicit root directory is provided.